# How create UI page in Momentics IDE?

Tags: blackberry-10, momentics

I try to developing mobile app for BlackBerry 10
So i have question: where is **ToolBox** to create UI or need to manualy write UI in code?
I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom left side, under Project Explorer you have **Components**, looks like this:
[image]

You can drag and drop from it into your QML files if you want. If it's not there go to **Window -> Show View -> Components**. But at least for me, manually writing is a lot faster